# Protractor wait unlimited period of time for Angular page to load

Tags: webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a protractor test that running on an Angular page that gets 4 push notification for second for unlimited period of time, the problem is that Protractor wait forever for the page to load, there is a way for stopping protractor for waiting angular?

```
it("Navigate to My Account window",function(){
    navigation.navigate_my_account();
    expect(navigation.getWindowsTitle()).toBe("Account window");
});
```

The test just click button and compere the title of the page with a String.

Answer (score 1):

Read [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/49), you should use `$interval` to poll requests, protractor will then know how to wait.

Alternatively, you could use `ignoreSynchronization` that way p-tor will not wait for angular requests. but you should use the first option, as the second one is disabling the core feature of protractor, the sync and wait for protractor.